# Why doesn't "function sayHi.alternate () {}" work?

Tags: javascript, function, public

I am having a hard time understanding Static scope in Javascript. Can anyone please explain the difference between the below two functions

It works fine if I do

```
function sayHi(){
        alert("Hi");
    }
    sayHi.alternate=function(){
        alert("Hola");
    }
    sayHi();
    sayHi.alternate();
```

But doenst work if I do

```
function sayHi(){
        alert("Hi");
    }
    function sayHi.alternate(){
        alert("Hola");
    }
    sayHi();
    sayHi.alternate();
```

As usual Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't valid javascript:

```
function sayHi.alternate(){
```

You can't assign a property when declaring a function this way.  You can only define a name to be used for the function.  That's why the other form is used when you're assigning it to an object property or assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
function sayHi.alternate(){
    alert("Hola");
}
```

...will give you a syntax error. That's because you cannot name your function `sayHi.alternate`.

However, since everything in Javascript is an object, *including functions*, you can simply treat your `sayHi` function as an object, and add a new method to it with:

```
sayHi.alternate = function(){
    alert("Hola");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write `function sayHi.alternate` you're trying to create a function called `sayHi.alternate`. Functions can't contain a period in their names, so `sayHi.alternate` is an invalid function name.

When you create `sayHi.alternate= function` you're creating a function called `alternate` inside the object `sayHi`.